# Running Totals for the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to create running totals based on the year in my query as i'm showing the last 3 years of sales and commissions in my query and want running yearly totals for those for each salesperson listed

Tried various ways to get the data to do this but haven't been able to.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT 'abc' AS CompanyCode, abc.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, 
                         SUM(abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceTotalSum, SUM(abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.CommissionAmt) AS CommissionAmtSum, DATENAME(month, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) 
                         AS Month, DATENAME(year, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS Year, DATEPART(m, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS MonthNumber
FROM            abc.AR_Customer INNER JOIN
                         abc.AR_SalespersonCommission ON abc.AR_Customer.ARDivisionNo = abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.ARDivisionNo AND abc.AR_Customer.CustomerNo = abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.CustomerNo INNER JOIN
                         abc.AR_Salesperson ON abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo = abc.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonDivisionNo AND 
                         abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo = abc.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonNo
GROUP BY abc.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, DATENAME(month, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), 
                         DATENAME(year, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), DATEPART(m, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate)
HAVING        (DATENAME(year, abc.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) > DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))

UNION

SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT 'XYZ' AS CompanyCode, xyz.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, 
                         SUM(xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceTotalSum, SUM(xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.CommissionAmt) AS CommissionAmtSum, DATENAME(month, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) 
                         AS Month, DATENAME(year, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS Year, DATEPART(m, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) AS MonthNumber
FROM            xyz.AR_Customer INNER JOIN
                         xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission ON xyz.AR_Customer.ARDivisionNo = xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.ARDivisionNo AND xyz.AR_Customer.CustomerNo = xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.CustomerNo INNER JOIN
                         xyz.AR_Salesperson ON xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo = xyz.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonDivisionNo AND 
                         xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo = xyz.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonNo
GROUP BY xyz.AR_Salesperson.SalespersonName, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonDivisionNo, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.SalespersonNo, DATENAME(month, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), 
                         DATENAME(year, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate), DATEPART(m, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate)
HAVING        (DATENAME(year, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) > DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))
```

I expect the output to have running totals for the InvoiceTotalSum and CommissionAmt for each salesperson for the last 3 years. So of course January will be 0 for each person but Feb through December will have a running total

Sample data and desired results below. Desired results are the highlighted columns

[Sample Data and Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJL2C.png)

Comment: @GordonLinoff sample data and desired results attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things before I go to the solution.

First, I am not sure why you need an `UNION` into your query. I can see the difference between `abc` and `xyz` but it still looks strange.
It is surely possible your query can be shortened/simplified, which would need more info to tell.

Second, I do not see a valid reason why the running total should be 0 for January.
Explanation about that:

- February (2nd month of the year): running total in your expected result contains the amount for 2 months
- March: 3 months
- April: 4 months
- ...

So January should contain the running total for 1 month (January itself).

Try the query below:

```
WITH MyData AS (
 <Please paste your query here>
)
SELECT CompanyCode, SalesPersonName, SalesPersonDivisionNo, InvoiceTotalSum,
SUM(InvoiceTotalSum) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPersonDivisionNo, SalesPersonNo, SalesPersonName, Year ORDER BY MonthNumber) AS InvoiceTotalRunningSum,
CommissionAmtSum,
SUM(CommissionAmtSum) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesPersonDivisionNo, SalesPersonNo, SalesPersonName, Year ORDER BY MonthNumber) AS CommissionAmtRunningSum,
Month, Year, MonthNumber
FROM MyData
ORDER BY CompanyCode, SalesPersonDivisionNo, SalesPersonNo, SalesPersonName, Year, MonthNumber
```

The magic takes place in the `PARTION BY`/`ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to review your query and simplify it. 
a few notes :

- if the CompanyCode is already existed within the database, join its table and link it with the current records instead of writing it manually.
- `DATENAME(year, ... )` the shorthand is `YEAR()`
- `DATEPART(m, ...)` the shorthand is `MONTH()`
- I encourage you to use aliases
- `(DATENAME(year, xyz.AR_SalespersonCommission.InvoiceDate) > DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE()))` will exclude the first year and include the current.So, 2019-3 = 2016, yours will get 2017,2018, and 2019, while it should get 2016,2017, and 2018.

for your InvoiceTotalRunningSum use :

```
SUM(InvoiceTotalSum) OVER (PARTITION BY SalespersonNo ORDER BY MonthNumber UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

this will do an accumulative sum on `InvoiceTotalSum` for each `SalespersonNo`. you can partition the records for each year, month ..etc. simply by adding more partitions, but I used your current query as sub-query, and did that instead :

read more about [SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

try it out :

```
SELECT 
    'abc' AS CompanyCode
,   SalespersonName
,   SalespersonDivisionNo
,   SalespersonNo
,   InvoiceTotalSum 
,   SUM(InvoiceTotalSum) OVER (PARTITION BY SalespersonNo ORDER BY MonthNumber UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) InvoiceTotalRunningSum
,   CommissionAmtSum
,   SUM(CommissionAmtSum) OVER (PARTITION BY SalespersonNo ORDER BY MonthNumber UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) CommissionAmtRunningSum
,   [Month]
,   [Year]
,   MonthNumber
FROM (
    SELECT
        'abc' AS CompanyCode
    ,   ars.SalespersonName
    ,   arsc.SalespersonDivisionNo
    ,   arsc.SalespersonNo
    ,   SUM(arsc.InvoiceTotal) InvoiceTotalSum
    ,   SUM(arsc.CommissionAmt) CommissionAmtSum
    ,   DATENAME(month, arsc.InvoiceDate) [Month]
    ,   YEAR(arsc.InvoiceDate) [Year]
    ,   MONTH(arsc.InvoiceDate) MonthNumber
    FROM            
        abc.AR_Customer arc
    INNER JOIN abc.AR_SalespersonCommission  arsc ON arc.ARDivisionNo = arsc.ARDivisionNo AND arc.CustomerNo = arsc.CustomerNo 
    INNER JOIN abc.AR_Salesperson ars ON arsc.SalespersonDivisionNo = ars.SalespersonDivisionNo AND arsc.SalespersonNo = ars.SalespersonNo
    GROUP BY 
        ars.SalespersonName
    ,   arsc.SalespersonDivisionNo
    ,   arsc.SalespersonNo
    ,   YEAR(arsc.InvoiceDate)
    ,   MONTH(arsc.InvoiceDate)
    ,   DATENAME(month, arsc.InvoiceDate)
    HAVING    
        YEAR(arsc.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3 AND YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 -- Only include the last three years (excluding current year)
) D
```